# Activate video camera in the background

Tags: android, camera

I want to activate the video camera while my application is in the background.
So in order to do it I created a service that start/stop the video camera...
The problem is that I need to create a `SurfaceView` in the main activity (the one that called to that service in my case) in order to `setPreviewDisplay`. But when my application is in the background I get `Application lost the surface` ERROR.

I know that I need a `SurfaceView` in order to activate the video camera, but there is a better solution to activate the video camera while my application is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I think the problem is that Service really isn't intended to handle UI-related classes the way Activity is.

Try packaging up all your camera code, including the SurfaceView setup, into an Activity.  Then have your Service invoke the activity by launching an Intent for that Activity.  Basically, all the Service does is decide when the camera is needed, and then launch the Activity.

I'm assuming you are okay with the fact that the camera preview will appear onscreen.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have an activity that start the camera service. but my problem is that I need to activate the camera only after my `application` is going to the background and by that i'm getting `Application lost the surface` ERROR.